# se puede crear una funcion que inicie el servidor en node js

Tags: nodejs, vue.js

estoy creando mi primer aplicacion CLI para terminal con **commander**

> visto que VueJs tiene un comando **vue ui** que activa un servidor local y trae una interfaz grafica. Eso es lo que me gustaria crear.

lo que me gustaria hacer es crear un comando, por ejemplo `cliapp serve` y que me inicie el servidor de node js. Dejo un pequeño ejemplo aver si me logro hacer entender.

```
import { program } from 'commander';
program.command('serve').action(() => {

// aqui tendria que traer una funcion que pueda iniciar un servidor local.

});
```

Comment: osea quieres que esa función ejecute algo como `node index.js`?

Comment: Exactamente, @Fedex7501 eso es lo que quiero lograr, pero no sé como jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar comandos externos con el módulo `child_process`:

```
import {program} from 'commander';
const { exec } = require("child_process");

program.command('serve').action(() => {
    exec("node index.js", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Muchas Graciasss!! es exactamente lo que necesitaba 